# Does Pokémon Go account have a region limit?

Tags: pokemon-go

For example, a Pokémon Go account can be logged in in Germany, and then I want to log it in Australia, does it work? Are there any region limit?

Comment: The purpose of the game is quite literally to travel around, so no of course there are no region restrictions, however this does _not_ mean you can use GPS spoofing methods and get away with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pokemon GO makes no attempts to limit where you can play the game -- after all, that would be counterproductive to the point of the game. Even more so with regional exclusives.

However, cheating the game through use of GPS spoofers and other methods may result in your account getting soft-banned or terminated. Typically, though, this check is pretty lenient -- if you suddenly teleport to Japan, the game will lock up. However, flying to Japan will not trigger the softban in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm informed there are no real regional limits, but you might get a "Soft Ban" if the app detects that you are traveling faster than possible.

Examples:

- if you're logged in in Germany, log out, and 5 minutes later log in at a position that isn't possible to reach in that time e.g. the United States.
- If you're logged in in a car or train or something that drives faster than a person could drive with a bicycle.

Comment: i got a error page  it showed the mail is locked, what's situation of it ?

Comment: how do i solve it?

Comment: did you use a GPS faker?

Comment: wow. i'm newer for this game , so don't understand it, the mail was locked , because of that kind of things? so, what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: I never got a soft ban, but I am travelling and playing in a train (that drives faster than my bike, luckily enough). Sometimes I put the game down, to re-open it several kilometers away, and my character jumps. Still not bans though.

Comment: it's amazing。。。

Comment: I've tested my Australian account while on holiday in the UK and had no problems.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that I used an incense while travelling in a bus going about 110 kph, and about a lot of Pokemon appeared, every single one (17 in a row) bolted after my first Pokeballs throw. I wonder if travelling fast pushes the definitive escape chance up.

Comment: @Mathias711 No ban because it's a legitimate time between jumps. You put your phone down and when you turn it on 15 minutes later the _time_ of 15 minutes justifies the jump.

Comment: @rensa It's possible. I would Razz + Great ball them unless they're really crappy

Comment: @Insane Yep, I razzberried + great balled all of them! But they all broke out and ran straight off, without fail. Even the ones that were, like, 15cp Pidgeys. It could be because they were brought in by insence, but I think the speed factor is more likely (or the combination of both!).

Comment: @rensa _all_ of them? are you sure you weren't soft banned and didn't know it? that's what a symptom of a soft ban is. every Pokemon runs away and you can't use Pokestops for a few hours!!

Comment: @Insane Okay, that sounds likely! I didn't hit any stops at the time, so I can't tell on that front. After 10 mins I put the phone away and let the incense expire; the next time I tried was after the bus had stopped a few hours later. So maybe it was a soft ban! it was also a bus from the international airport, and I'd just caught a bunch of Pokemon at lured spots there...

Comment: @rensa Usually you don't get soft banned unless you travel a distance in an unrealistic amount of time. Meaning if you turn your phone off, fly to Australia, then turn it on, you won't be banned because the flight time is long enough to justify the distance. If you are using a GPS spoofer be careful..

Comment: @Insane No location spoofing; it was just after a London-to-Sydney flight. *shrugs*

Comment: @rensa I would use 'report high priority issue' in game and tell Niantic. Seriously you shouldn't be getting soft banned for a legitimate flight